# Multiple GET requests for HTTP client (socket programming)

Tags: python, sockets, httpclient

I am trying to make a client that is able to request multiple GET requests before closing the connection. Currently, I am able to send 1 GET request. Subsequent GET requests throws `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`

I assume that there is an error due to the request being sent too early? not too sure, any help is appreciated!

Client source code:

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect(('localhost', 8000))

clientSocket.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost\r\n\r\n")
response = clientSocket.recv(4096)
print(response.decode())

# second GET request
clientSocket.send(b"GET /file.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost\r\n\r\n")
response = clientSocket.recv(4096)
print(response.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...", line 12, in <module>
    response = clientSocket.recv(4096)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Server source code

```
import socket

def handle_request(request):
    headers = request.split('\n')
    filename = headers[0].split()[1]
    if filename == '/':
        filename = '/index.html'

    try:
        fin = open('.' + filename)
        content = fin.read()
        fin.close()

        response = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n' + content
    except FileNotFoundError:
        response = 'HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND\n\nFile Not Found'

    return response

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Listening on port 8000 ...')

while True:    
    client_connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024).decode()
    response = handle_request(request)
    client_connection.sendall(response.encode())
    client_connection.close()

# Close socket
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: can you add full error traceback

Answer (score 0):

The answer was initially written before the code of the server was shown. After more was known about the server it went clear, that the original server did not actually properly implemented HTTP keep-alive, i.e. the assumptions made in the answer were true.

Original answer:
You are trying to implement HTTP keep-alive. The server does not need to implement this in the first place, i.e. it is allowed to close the connection immediately after sending the response.  Nothing is known about the server and its configuration, but this might be the case here.

Comment: I have added the server source code, but I do not think the server is the issue? not too sure

Comment: @hui13 well your server closes the connection after it sends a response, doesn't it?  by the way, the way you use recv doesn't always work in the real world, but I guess it's good enough for a demonstration on localhost

Comment: @user253751 Hmm, I tested without closing the connection but it causes the client to not receive anything. Also, since it is in a while True loop, wouldnt the connection should be open again after?

Comment: @hui13 Your server waits for a connection, reads a request from the connection, sends a response to the connection, then closes it. If the server doesn't close it, then your server waits for a connection, reads a request from the connection, sends a response to the connection, then ignores it for the rest of all eternity.

Comment: Meanwhile your client creates a connection, sends a request on the connection, receives a response on the connection, sends another request on a connection, and waits for another response on the connection, then closes it. See the mismatch?

Comment: @user253751 ohhh, I see! I moved the connection out of the while loop and added a null byte ('\0') at the end of the content on the server side and used that for my client side to recognise the end of a response. Which works well! But do you think there is a better way to do so?

Comment: @hui13: the proper way to recognize the end of the response is to actually implement the HTTP protocol. Messages have a clearly defined syntax and from the message header it can be determined how the body needs to be parsed and thus were it ends. See [RFC 7230 section 3 "Message Format"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3)

Comment: And more specifically, at [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3 "Message Body Length"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3), which outlines the rules you need to follow to determine the end of an HTTP message.